# What's the proper format for page_range in Google Cloud Print's Cloud Job Ticket?

Tags: api, google-cloud-print

I'm working with Google Cloud Print and I've got most everything I need working fine. However, I can't find sufficient information on how to format the `page_range`. The way I figured out proper formatting for other options was to use the [simulate page's Third Party Printing Gadget](https://www.google.com/cloudprint/simulate.html) to print a document, then use the API to look up the job's ticket.

However, when I set a page range to print, the `page_range` in the ticket always has the same value:

```
"page_range" => array:1 [▼
  "interval" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
      "start" => 1
    ]
  ]
]
```

The prints come out as expected with only the specified ranges printed. Some example ranges I tried on a 3-page PDF:

- `2`
- `2-3`
- `1`

If I leave the range in the form blank, I end up with an empty array:

```
"page_range" => []
```

Anyone out there know how this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the proper way to set the values, but I'm not sure why those other tickets' `page_range`s are all identical.

The answer is pretty simple; You just set a `start` and `end` value. I'm working with PHP and had to cast the values to integers, since they were being read as strings and that caused Google to reject the ticket.

Here's an example that prints first and second pages:

```
"page_range" => array:1 [▼
  "interval" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
      "start" => 1,
      "end" => 2
    ]
  ]
]
```